# Conditional atomic mongo remove with different results

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

There's a collection of items in mongo database. I want to implement a method that removes an item, provided its `id`.

However, I only want to remove the item if it has, say, a `deletable` property set to `true`. Then, I want to distinguish the following situations (errors) to handle them different:

- The item exists and the `deletable` property set to `true` => remove it
- The item exists and the `deletable` property set to `false` => don't remove it, `raise Error1`
- The item does not exist => nothing to remove, `raise Error2`

Assuming the application is multithreaded and there might be several workers adding, removing and modifying items, is there a way to handle such case correctly?

As for now, I can either remove or skip silently an item with specified `id` and `deletable` property or issue a few queries one by one to handle all situations, but it might not thread safe.

I'm using `pymongo` to access the database if it matters.

Comment: Why do you need the distinction? If you think you really do then what is wrong with just trying to query for the "id" existing to decide which error to return?

Comment: I actually do need the distinction to correctly generate the HTTP response status code: 200, 404 and 400. Did not really get what you mean by "just trying to query for the 'id' existing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will never get this in a single statement as there will be no differentiation between "how many" fields matched your conditions. But you can just do this with logical conditions and an additional find where the first attempt did not remove any documents. Just use the write concern response to see what happened.

```python
resp = db.collection.remove({ 'id': id, 'deletable': True }, w=1)
if resp['n'] == 0:
  doc = db.collection.find_one({ 'id': id, 'deletable': False })
  if doc is None:
    # this would be not found 404
  else:
    # this would the not deletable
else:
  # this would be deleted 200
```

So checking the returned value with any write concern applied let's you know if the delete occurred and the following `find_one` let's you know if the document simply was not found or was just marked as deletable `false` at the time.

Comment: I understand your approach. I'm only afraid of that you have messed up the `if`s and `else`es.. `if resp['n'] == 0`: that means that nothing has been deleted, right? So I want to return 404, not 200 in such case.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I can't call this an atomic operation, but this looks to be working exactly as I wished in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: @Ixanezis Which is basically what I stated at the begining. MongoDB does not differentiate "why" something does not match. It either does or it doesn't. So if you need the distinction then you need to test for that condition. This can never be a single statement.

Comment: Yes, I got it. BTW, I was trying to remove your `;` and round brackets to look more like pep8, but this was only a 4 character edit %|.